# Discord py having trouble with getting roles for mute command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So the entirety of this command works but I keep getting an error that says:

```
NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role.
```

I have tried using so many things from the role id to discord.guild.get_role and I keep getting the same error. Any help is appreciated!

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
     if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        await member.add_roles(member, role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="User Muted!", description="**{0}** was muted by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.", color=0xff00f6)
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is partly outdated and the reason you have this error is coming from:

```py
await member.add_roles(member, role)
```

Before v1.0, you needed to pass `member` in the method's argument but it's no longer necessary. So here, you're trying to add a `discord.Role` that is a `discord.Member`.

Other parts that are outdated:

- `pass_context=True` is also no longer necessary, you can remove it.
- `bot.say` doesn't exist, you can use `ctx.send(embed=embed)`.

You can read more about the v1.0 migration here : [Migrating to v1.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
await member.add_roles(role)
```

That is what you are looking for, as MrSpaar just told you.

Another suggestion I would like to make is doing the following.

Change this

```
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
```

To this:

```
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("You must specify a user.")
        return
    if not reason:
        await ctx.send("You must specify a reason.")
        return
```

If you have any further questions let me know.